# Default scope of a null datetime. How to index?

Tags: mysql, database

In my app, there is a very large table `(>40 million rows)` that will have a default scope set on the model. 
The default scope will look at a specific `DATETIME` column and check that it IS `NULL`. The `DATETIME` column will probably never be used to search for a specific date. Should I be using an index here, and if so, how?

The `WHERE <column_name> IS NULL` will be added to almost every single query made on this table from the app. On the one hand, since the column is essentially being treated as a `boolean`, I am tempted to think that it should not be indexed. However, it seems that with such a huge table, an index should provide value, especially for a query like

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table_name> WHERE <column_name> IS NULL`

I am also a bit confused about how I should index, since the `WHERE` clause will be appended to every query. I do not think that it would make sense to created an index on all columns of this table. This is being done in MySQL. Thanks

Comment: Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to post

Comment: What is a “a default scope set on the model”?

Comment: Questions about database & SQL only might be better posted on [dba.StackExchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @BasilBourque This is being done in Rails, so setting a default scope on the model means that the ORM (Active Record) will automatically append the default scope query to the query that Active Record generates. In this case, instead of `SELECT COUNT(*) from foo_table` (unscoped query), Active Record will generate `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo_table WHERE bar_column IS NULL`

Comment: @AriK. Good to know — You should tag your Question, or mention such facts in the text of the Question.

Comment: I don't know about about MySQL, but some advanced databases such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) can build a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) based on a predicate such as checking for NULL. See [this Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107075/19079) by Erwin Brandstetter on sibling site Question, [*Do I want an index if all I care to query is field not null*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/107068/19079).

Comment: How many datetime columns? What about a `normalized`database, adding extra tables for all datetime columns with the tables Primary Key as Foreign Key and then `LEFT JOIN` and filter for `IS NULL`? Or avoid `NULL`by using a not valid datetime (.e.g. something a thousand years in the past) as default value, index the fields and  filter for the datetime.